# Who (if any) is the highest-ranking U.S. official who has accused Israel of committing a war crime and/or human rights violation?

Tags: united-states, israel, human-rights, war-crime

It has been said that that Israel is [violating human rights and committing war crimes](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2023/06/rights-civil-society-members-are-being-violated-all-entities-israel-and), yet the United States consistently blocks any condemnation of Israel by utilizing its veto power in the UN, and I can't think of a US official who agreed with this consensus and called any of Israel's actions a war crime or a human rights violation. Is there any? Preferably they did so while in their official position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question:**
>
> Who is the highest-ranking U.S. official who has accused Israel of committing a war crime and/or human rights violation?

President Jimmy Carter in Foreign Policy Magazine.  He wrote an op-ed article along with ex-Ireland President Marty Robinson.

> **[Jimmy Carter and Israel: 10 of President's Notable Quotes](https://www.newsmax.com/fastfeatures/jimmy-carter-israel-quotes/2014/12/29/id/596734/)**
>
> "There is no humane or legal justification for the way the Israeli Defense Forces are conducting this war (*note:  seems to be [2014 War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Gaza_War)*)," the two men wrote in the article. "Israeli bombs, missiles, and artillery have pulverized large parts of Gaza, including thousands of homes, schools, and hospitals. More than 250,000 people have been displaced from their homes in Gaza. Hundreds of Palestinian noncombatants have been killed. Much of Gaza has lost access to water and electricity completely. This is a humanitarian catastrophe. There is never an excuse for deliberate attacks on civilians in conflict. These are war crimes. This is true for both sides."

Didn't use the term War Crime, but accusing Israel of knowingly attacking a neutral ship in International Waters, maybe US Secretary of State Dean Rusk in response to the Israeli Attack on the **[USS Liberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Liberty_incident#USS_Liberty)** in 1967.  It was a lightly armed signals intelligence ship the US had monitoring events in international waters off the coast during the Israeli Egyptian Six Day War.  Israel attacked the ship over a period of 2 hours,  killing 34, wounded 171 Americans.

> **[Secretary of State Dean Rusk](http://www.gtr5.com/quotes/rusk.htm)** 10 June 1967
>
> "But I was never satisfied with the Israeli explanation. Their sustained attack to disable and sink Liberty precluded an assault by accident or some trigger-happy local commander. Through diplomatic channels we refused to accept their explanations. I didn't believe them then, and I don't believe them to this day. The attack was outrageous."

President Eisenhower also had issues with Israel after they fire bombed the US embassy in Egypt in 1954.  The **[Lavon Affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavon_Affair)** named after the Israeli Defense minister who resigned over the operation (Operation Susannah).

> **[The Lavon Affair: When Israel Firebombed U.S. Installations](https://www.wrmea.org/1992-july/the-lavon-affair-when-israel-firebombed-u.s.-installations.html)**
>
> "I just can't figure out what the Israelis think they're up to...Maybe they think they just can't survive without more land...but I don't see how they can survive without coming to some honorable and peaceful terms with the whole Arab world that surrounds them." U.S. President Dwight D. Eisenhower, October 1956

Comment: The Jimmy Carter quote was in 2014, long after he held any US government position. The Rusk and Eisenhower quotes are disapproving or condemnations, but don't explicitly "accuse[] Israel of committing a war crime and/or human rights violation".

Answer (score 3):

While in office, Obama [said](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/the-press-office/2013/03/21/remarks-president-barack-obama-people-israel) some such stuff, but not in super-strong terms of condemnation, nor did call these outright human rights violations:

> It’s not right to prevent Palestinians from farming their lands; or restricting a student’s ability to move around the West Bank; or displace Palestinian families from their homes.

In case somebody wonders, that is a nod to some [usual complaints](https://youtu.be/i9YJdF2pkHQ?t=291) from human rights groups.

Answer (score 3):

It'd be a mistake to take blocking UN condemnations of Israel as a blanket denial of human rights abuses on the U.S.'s part. Take, for example, last year's [Report on Human Rights Practices: Israel, West Bank and Gaza](https://www.state.gov/reports/2022-country-reports-on-human-rights-practices/israel-west-bank-and-gaza/), issued by the State Department.

> Significant human rights issues included credible reports of: unlawful
> or arbitrary killings; arbitrary or unjust detention, including of
> Palestinians in Israel and the occupied territories; restrictions on
> Palestinians residing in Jerusalem including arbitrary or unlawful
> interference with privacy, family, and home; substantial interference
> with the freedom of peaceful assembly and association; arbitrary or
> unlawful interference with privacy; punishment of family members for
> alleged offenses by a relative; restrictions on freedom of expression
> and media including censorship; harassment of nongovernmental
> organizations; violence against asylum seekers and migrants; violence
> or threats of violence against Palestinians and members of national,
> racial, or ethnic minority groups; and labor rights abuses against
> foreign workers and Palestinian workers.

The president and high-level diplomatic officials may not be out there everyday saying "Israel commits human rights violations," but they are also *diplomats*, and Israel is a U.S. ally.